# Why am I seeing pairs 1 and 2 failing on a newly rewired Cat6 run throughout my house?

Tags: networking, cat6, cabling, patch-panel

I have replaced Cat5e and pulled Cat6 cable throughout my house.

I installed a few extra wall ports so we could hard wire game consoles etc. The issue seems to be that when checking the ports and corresponding patch panel port I’m getting a failure for pairs 1 and 2.

I’m using all new Cat6 patch cables and have re-punched the ports and patch panel several times. I’m using a Klein Scout Pro 2 to test and every port shows:

- `12345678` with the 1 and 2 blinking.

`345678` I could understand one port, but multiples are a head scratcher.[image]

Comment: Did you punch-down for T568A or T568B? Did you test the Klein Scout Pro 2 on a known-good patch cable?

Comment: I punched down T568B at both ends. All patch cables are new and work fine.

Comment: Patch cables: 1ft Cat6 from patch panel to switch.

Comment: Cat6 UTP solid wire was used for the attic and drop locations. Cat6 stranded patch cables were used for device to wall/patch panel.

Comment: My setup is by no means elaborate. The purpose for replacing the cat5e was increase some bandwidth and add a few locations throughout our house. My son likes to do some gaming either on console or pc. And list grows. So since I have been home I created a few projects. 
If I can I will post a pic of the network panel.

Comment: All Cat6 that was used to punch down to wall keystones and the patch panel was Cat6 solid UTP.

Comment: How many of your punched cables are showing these issues?

Comment: I bought a box of 1000ft of Cat6 riser cable. Not stranded. All keystones are Cat6. Nothing is shielded. 
The location for the patch panel etc. is upstairs in a structured network panel. 
I have the router, 2 modems (1 for the phone, the other for the internet). I’m using a Netgear 16 port gigabit switch. I have 12 port mini patch panel that I mounted.

Comment: Interesting enough 7 locations. In all locations I have redone the punch down stripping back approx 3 inches of jacket to insure good pairs.

Comment: I cannot post any pics yet, not enough post.

Comment: Before you get too crazy with it, fresh batteries in the tester right?

Comment: Any progress in troubleshooting?

Comment: Yes, so my cheap tester revealed all lines were good last night. I’m going to double check today. Maybe my Klein is faulty, not sure but cables check out good. Wiring is good, so this prevents the potential insanity.

Comment: Thank you for the help and guidance.

Comment: You are welcome. I had an old fluke networks tester like this one, it wouldn't display on the LCD when the battery was going. But would always show the same two pins flashing when it was in a bat low condition. You can always write up an answer yourself if you want.